Threads Meta API/Auth Callback URLs
What does this error mean?
Whats wrong with my Callback Urls?
I only want to set these URLs, that I can gain access to some user accounts about this link:
https://threads.net/oauth/authorize
  ?client_id=<THREADS_APP_ID>
  &redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>
  &scope=<SCOPE>
  &response_type=code
  &state=<STATE> // Optional

But I think the REDIRECT_URI must be the same as the other URL that I can't set.

I also tried this with different URLs. For example https://example.com/auth/callback, but still the same error.

This sounds like a facebook bug, assuming you used a real domain you own and not example.com. Are you certain there's no spaces in front of the URL? Contact support.

When you add the first URL, you must click on the dropdown under the input field to add the URL

